# reason: actual value has 1 more key(s) than expected:

Tags: cucumber, karate

I am running karate tests.

I am posting a request object and i recieve a response object . however in the response object i have one extra field populated .How will i handle the scenario ?

the following is my test

```
@NFRSubscription.feature
Feature: NFR Subscription API Tests

  Background:
    * url __arg.test_service.url
    * configure ssl = false
    * configure httpVersion = 'http2'

  Scenario: Create/Patch/Delete NRF subscription by nfInstanceId subscription condition
    * def subscriptionId = ''
    * def createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdRequest = read('subscription/subscriptionCreateRequest.json')
    * def patchSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse = read('subscription/subscriptionPatchResponse.json')
    * def createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse = createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdRequest


    # Create the NRF subscription by nfInstanceId
    Given path '/nnrf-nfm/v1/subscriptions/'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    And print createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdRequest
    And request createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdRequest
    When method post
    Then status 201
    And match response == createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse
    And match response.subscriptionId == '#present'
    And print response
```

the content of subscription/subscriptionCreateRequest.json is as follows.

```
{
  "nfStatusNotificationUri": "http://localhost:8080/ip/test",
  "reqNfInstanceId": "9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76", 
  "subscrCond": {
    "nfInstanceId": "9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76"
  },
  "validityTime": "2022-02-18T10:15:15Z",
  "reqNotifEvents": [
    "NF_REGISTERED"
  ],
  "plmnId": {"mcc": "454", "mnc" : "93" },
  "nid": "2465aEB5ff1",
  "notifCondition": {
    "monitoredAttributes": [
      "testattri"
    ]
  },
  "reqNfType": "NRF",
  "reqNfFqdn": "com.openet.com",
  "reqSnssais": [
    { "sst": 10, "sd": "aA82a7" }
  ],
  "reqPlmnList": [
    {"mcc": "454", "mnc" : "93" }
  ],
  "reqSnpnList": [
    {"mcc": "454", "mnc" : "93" }
  ],
  "servingScope": [
    "any string"
  ],
  "nrfSupportedFeatures": "CBAdEd1bef9B118EAd8d5bAfc66B59c1D292fD821d"
}
```

the content of the file subscription/subscriptionPatchResponse.json is as follows.

```
{
  "nfStatusNotificationUri": "http://localhost:8080/ip/test",
  "reqNfInstanceId": "9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76", 
  "subscrCond": {
    "nfInstanceId": "9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76"
  },
  "validityTime": "2023-03-07T23:20:50Z",
  "reqNotifEvents": [
    "NF_REGISTERED"
  ],
  "plmnId": {"mcc": "454", "mnc" : "93" },
  "nid": "2465aEB5ff1",
  "notifCondition": {
    "monitoredAttributes": [
      "testattri"
    ]
  },
  "reqNfType": "NRF",
  "reqNfFqdn": "com.openet.com",
  "reqSnssais": [
    { "sst": 10, "sd": "aA82a7" }
  ],
  "reqPlmnList": [
    {"mcc": "454", "mnc" : "93" }
  ],
  "reqSnpnList": [
    {"mcc": "454", "mnc" : "93" }
  ],
  "servingScope": [
    "any string"
  ],
  "nrfSupportedFeatures": "CBAdEd1bef9B118EAd8d5bAfc66B59c1D292fD821d"
}
```

in the response I would expect a new field called subscriptionId .

my test fails at the moment with the following error .

```
16:00:57  com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: NFRSubscription.feature:24 - path: $, actual: {nfStatusNotificationUri=http://localhost:8080/ip/test, reqNfInstanceId=9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76, subscrCond={nfInstanceId=9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76}, subscriptionId=608425, validityTime=2022-02-18T10:15:15Z, reqNotifEvents=["NF_REGISTERED"], plmnId={mcc=454, mnc=93}, nid=2465aEB5ff1, notifCondition={monitoredAttributes=["testattri"]}, reqNfType=NRF, reqNfFqdn=com.openet.com, reqSnssais=[{"sst":10,"sd":"aA82a7"}], reqPlmnList=[{"mcc":"454","mnc":"93"}], reqSnpnList=[{"mcc":"454","mnc":"93"}], servingScope=["any string"], nrfSupportedFeatures=CBAdEd1bef9B118EAd8d5bAfc66B59c1D292fD821d}, expected: {nfStatusNotificationUri=http://localhost:8080/ip/test, reqNfInstanceId=9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76, subscrCond={nfInstanceId=9c79364e-99e1-42a8-ada1-86c31ad1fa76}, validityTime=2022-02-18T10:15:15Z, reqNotifEvents=["NF_REGISTERED"], plmnId={mcc=454, mnc=93}, nid=2465aEB5ff1, notifCondition={monitoredAttributes=["testattri"]}, reqNfType=NRF, reqNfFqdn=com.openet.com, reqSnssais=[{"sst":10,"sd":"aA82a7"}], reqPlmnList=[{"mcc":"454","mnc":"93"}], reqSnpnList=[{"mcc":"454","mnc":"93"}], servingScope=["any string"], nrfSupportedFeatures=CBAdEd1bef9B118EAd8d5bAfc66B59c1D292fD821d}, reason: actual value has 1 more key(s) than expected: {subscriptionId=608425}
```

any idea how should i formulate `createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse` object to handle an extra dynamically generated field . in other words how can i do the following

add response.subscriptionId into createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse and then compare response and
createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse object .

```
And match response == createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse
```

Comment: downvoting this question because it is not a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - if you really want help, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the test to add the subscriptionId field in the response object and then asserted it .

```
# Create the NRF subscription by nfInstanceId
Given path '/nnrf-nfm/v1/subscriptions/'
And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
And print createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdRequest
And request createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdRequest
When method post
Then status 201
And match response.subscriptionId == '#present'
And print response
And set createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse.subscriptionId = response.subscriptionId
And match response == createSubscriptionByNfInstanceIdResponse
```